# Newtonsoft.Json fails deserializing valid JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm doing some calling of some REST services and deserializing the results I'm getting into C# objects. Everything looks pretty much by the book, and for the most part everything is fine, however I have one section of my JSON which throws the deserializer off and gives the not very helpful error message:

> Unexpected token when deserializing object: StartObject. Path 'channels.results[1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RWpwtn)', line 1, position 636.

So I went and isolated that part of my code and JSON to see if I could figure out what was wrong, and currently I have this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RWpwtn which also fails (Though if it gets cast to a dynamic it seems to work, at least for the most part):

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string JSON = "{\"id\" : 19,\"name\" : \"Vidensdeling\",\"sortOrder\" : 0,\"breakRightsInheritance\" : false,\"canContainItems\" : false,\"external\" : false,\"canOnlyEditItsOwn\" : null,\"parentChannelId\" : null,\"inheritedParentChannelId\" : null,\"itemCount\" : 0,\"permissionTarget\" : null,\"permissionTargetType\" : null,\"childChannelIds\" : [],\"contentTypeIds\" : [],\"mandatoryPrincipalIds\" : [],\"suggestedPrincipalIds\" : [],\"readRightsPrincipalIds\" : [],\"writeRightsPrincipalIds\" : [],\"visibleInCurrentView\" : null,\"mandatoryForCurrentUser\" : null,\"suggestedForCurrentUser\" : null,\"personalSelectedForCurrentUser\" : null,\"writeAllowedForCurrentUser\" : null,\"readAllowedForCurrentUser\" : null}";
        ChannelDtoV1 obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChannelDtoV1>(JSON);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Id);
    }
}

public class ChannelDtoV1 
{
    //Data properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public bool BreakRightsInheritance { get; set; }
    public bool CanContainItems { get; set; }
    public bool External { get; set; }
    public bool? CanOnlyEditItsOwn { get; set; }
    public int? ParentChannelId { get; set; }
    public int? InheritedParentChannelId { get; set; }
    public int ItemCount { get; set; }
    public string PermissionTarget { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(KVPEnumConverter<PermissionTargetType>))]
    public PermissionTargetType? PermissionTargetType { get; set; }

    //Collection properties
    public ICollection<int> ChildChannelIds { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> ContentTypeIds { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> MandatoryPrincipalIds { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> SuggestedPrincipalIds { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> ReadRightsPrincipalIds { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> WriteRightsPrincipalIds { get; set; }

    //Computed properties
    public bool? VisibleInCurrentView { get; set; }
    public bool? MandatoryForCurrentUser { get; set; }
    public bool? SuggestedForCurrentUser { get; set; }
    public bool? PersonalSelectedForCurrentUser { get; set; }
    public bool? WriteAllowedForCurrentUser { get; set; }
    public bool? ReadAllowedForCurrentUser { get; set; }

    public ChannelDtoV1()
    {
        ChildChannelIds = new List<int>();
        MandatoryPrincipalIds = new List<int>();
        SuggestedPrincipalIds = new List<int>();
        ReadRightsPrincipalIds = new List<int>();
        WriteRightsPrincipalIds = new List<int>();
        ContentTypeIds = new List<int>();
    }
}

public enum PermissionTargetType
{
    BussinessApp = 1
}

public class KVPEnumConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("name");
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
        writer.WritePropertyName("value");
        writer.WriteValue((int)value);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType is T;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object rtnObj = null;
        while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName && (string)reader.Value == "value")
            {
                reader.Read(); // proceed to value
                rtnObj = Enum.Parse(typeof(T), reader.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
        return rtnObj ?? default(T);
    }
}
```

Do anyone have any idea as to what might be causing this?

Comment: dotnetfiddles can linkrot so you should paste all of the code in to your question as well (but by all means keep the link to the fiddle).

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake, I guess this post was just the motivation I needed.

The error stems from the KVPEnumConverter looking too far ahead instead of returning if the value is null. 
All I had to do was to introduce a null check like this:

```
&& reader.TokenType != JsonToken.Null
```